# Multi-year travel medical insurance for Russian multi-year visa

Tags: visas, russia, insurance

When applying for a multi-year Russian business visa you have to provide a letter of proof that says you have travel medical insurance for the visa validity period, which in this case can be for two or more years. Finding travel medical insurance that is valid for multiple years is easy in for example Europe. But where can multi-year travel medical insurance be found in the United States that will allow getting the required letter of proof?

Most major U.S. insurance companies only seem to provide single trip or one year travel insurance, but not for multiple years at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention obtaining insurance in the USA.  According to the Russian Embassy in the USA you only need to provide proof of medical insurance covering the period of the first visit not the validity of the visa.

http://www.russianembassy.org/page/business-visa

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarifying that. I have previously applied for a similar visa from another country where the Russian consulate required proof of insurance for the entire trip period, which is why I assumed it would be the same when applying from the U.S.